# Data Preparation of a given .CSV

Tags: pandas, dataframe

test_sales
[image]

I would like to get a new data_set with the following column structure:

```
#the structure of the task [new csv]
1) order_number
2) number_of_orders_past_3_months
3) gross_sum_orders_past_3_months
4) number_of_orders_future_3_months
5) gross_sum_orders_future_3_months
# The produced data frame should be unique by order number.
```

I have done the following but I am not sure if it is right:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('test_sales')
df2 = df1.to_csv('order_count_sum.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('order_count_sum.csv')

df2['order_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['order_datetime'])
df2['number_of_orders_past_3_months'] = df2.groupby('order_number')['order_number'].value_counts().reset_index(drop = True)
df2['gross_sum_orders_past_3_months'] = df2.groupby(['order_number']).rolling(3, min_periods = 1, on = 'order_datetime')['gross_value'].sum().reset_index( drop = True)
df2.head(20)
```

the new .csv
[image]

May I know how can I get the following:

4. number_of_orders_future_3_months
5. gross_sum_orders_future_3_months